# writing/reading structure/class data in android

Tags: java, android, file-io

well basically I want to do this,

```
class myclass
{
    int a1;
    float b1;
    char c1;     //This is a single character
}
List<myclass> obs;
```

now at run-time this obs variable as it is a list will contain array of the myclass instances
whose size we get `obs.size();`

So, how to write this data to file say "data1.bin" as binary using OutputStream or some thing similar. But this is to be done in Android OS.

I did something like this in c++ like

```
class myclass
{
    int a1;
    float b1;
    char c1;
}

myclass student1;

ofstream output_file("students.data", ios::binary);
output_file.write((char*)&student1, sizeof(student1));
output_file.close()
```

But How to do this in Android OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to dump your class to file, let the class implement Serializable and java (or Dalvik VM on android) will do this for you behind the scene.

```
class MyClass implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    int a1;
    float b1;
    char c1;     //This is a single character
}


private File file;
private MyClass myClass;

private void writeIt() throws IOException {

    ObjectOutputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        stream.writeObject(myClass);
    } 
    finally {
        if(stream != null) {
            stream.close();
        }
    }
}

private MyClass readIt() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    ObjectInputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        return (MyClass) stream.readObject();
    } 
    finally {
        if(stream != null) {
            stream.close();
        }
    }
}
```